# How can I avoid most vexing parse with direct value initialization?

Tags: c++, initialization

After reading *[Most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse)*, I understand the following code is also ambiguous

```
T x();
```

On the one hand, it can be interpreted as a function declaration which returns an object of `T`. On the other hand, it can also be interpreted as a variable definition, and object `x` is [value-initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization).

I understand I can use uniform initialization like the following code to avoid conflict:

```
T x{};
```

I also understand if `T` is a (non-[POD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_data_structure) before C++11) class and the following default initialization actually equals value initialization

```
T x;
```

Meanwhile, if direct initialization is not necessary, we can use [copy initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization):

```
T x = T();
```

However, I think any of the three solutions have their limitation. I know if there are some arguments, I can also use an extra pair of parentheses:

```
T x((arg));
```

I want to adopt this strategy, but the following code does not work

```
T x(());
```

Are there are some better solutions with direct value initialization?

Comment: `auto x = T();` - leave direct initialisation in the dark ages where it belongs.

Comment: Go with `T x{};`

Comment: What are the limitations of uniform initialization?

Comment: And what do you mean by "better" (otherwise this is just opinion based)

Comment: @MartinBonner It appears after C++11, and sometimes uniform initialization seems to differ from value initialization, e.g. some constructors in `std::vector`

Comment: One downfall (depends on how you feel about it) is `T x{...}` will use the `std::initializer_list` constructor if present.  That means `std::vector<int> foo{10, 0};` is a vector of `{10, 0}` while `auto foo = std::vector<int>(10, 0)` produces `{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}`

Comment: @MartinBonner I want a possible direct value initialization solution(maybe my demand is too strict...)

Comment: @NathanOliver: But does that ever apply to value initialization, or only when parameters are supplied?  This question is about value initialization only.

Comment: @RichardHodges I know there are copy elision, but what if I deleted copy constructor?

Comment: @BenVoigt It only kicks in when values are provided.  AFAIK for all types `T`, `T x{};` will value initialize `x`.

Comment: @calvin I have provided an answer to explain.

Comment: @RichardHodges I saw your answer, and that seems to work only on C++17. Is there any workarounds to employ this strategy in some earlier C++ versions?

Comment: @calvin always write move constructors where possible. If before c++11, upgrade the compiler and get out of the dark ages :)

Comment: `T x()` is not ambiguous. It is a declaration of a function named `x` that takes no arguments and returns an object of type `T`. This is **not** the "most vexing parse", as your link makes clear.

Comment: @PeteBecker My understanding of the link is that a "most vexing parse" is a statement which can be viewed as a variable definition or a function declaration. In this case, C++ standard requires it to be interpreted as the a function declaration. Consider that `T x()` are be viewed as both, so I think this is a "most vexing parse". However I agree with your point that the word "ambiguous" may not suitable here.

Comment: @calvin -- if you read the page in the link, there is no mention of anything resembling `T x()`. That one is simple, and not at all "vexing".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use copy initialisation and rely on C++17's guarantee that copy elision will happen.

For example:

```
struct Foo
{
    Foo() = default;
    Foo(Foo const&) = delete;
};

int main()
{
    auto f = Foo();
}
```

https://godbolt.org/g/9tbkjZ

Comment: At last, a way to actually uniformly initialize objects \o/

Comment: @NathanOliver Let's talk about `auto f = Foo{};`  ;)

Comment: @M.M ssh! You'll start a riot.