# Compilation errors when trying to add data to a map in C++

Tags: c++

I am having trouble adding elements to a map in c++.

```
class myClass{
    private:
        string s;
    public:
        myClass(const string &s_1);
};

myClass::myClass(const string &s_1){
    s = s_1;
}
```

I need to create a map that can hold multiple instances of this class.

```
#include <map>
using std::map;
#include <utility>
using std::pair;
#include "myclass.h"

int main(){
    map <string, pair<myClass, string>> myMap;
    myClass m("something");
    string identity = "identity";
    string attribute = "attribute";
    pair<myClass, string> p (m, attribute);
    myMap[identity] = p; 
}
```

On first glance this looked completely fine to me, but when I tried to compile it, I ran into a lot of issues. Haven't been able to figure out what it could be.

This is what I get when I try to compile, and it is not even half of it:

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/bits/unique_ptr.h:37:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/bits/locale_conv.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/locale:43,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/regex:44,
                 from h.h:11,
                 from main.cpp:10:
/usr/include/c++/7/tuple: In instantiation of ‘std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(std::tuple<_Args1 ...>&, std::tuple<_Args2 ...>&, std::_Index_tuple<_Indexes1 ...>, std::_Index_tuple<_Indexes2 ...>) [with _Args1 = {const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&}; long unsigned int ..._Indexes1 = {0}; _Args2 = {}; long unsigned int ..._Indexes2 = {}; _T1 = const std::basic_string<char>; _T2 = std::pair<myClass, std::basic_string<char> >]’:
/usr/include/c++/7/tuple:1641:63:   required from ‘std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(std::piecewise_construct_t, std::tuple<_Args1 ...>, std::tuple<_Args2 ...>) [with _Args1 = {const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&}; _Args2 = {}; _T1 = const std::basic_string<char>; _T2 = std::pair<myClass, std::basic_string<char> >]’
/usr/include/c++/7/ext/new_allocator.h:136:4:   required from ‘void __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::construct(_Up*, _Args&& ...) [with _Up = std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, std::pair<myClass, std::basic_string<char> > >; _Args = {const std::piecewise_construct_t&, std::tuple<const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&>, std::tuple<>}; _Tp = std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, std::pair<myClass, std::basic_string<char> > > >]’
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/alloc_traits.h:475:4:   required from ‘static void std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<_CharT> >::construct(std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<_CharT> >::allocator_type&, _Up*, _Args&& ...) [with _Up = std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, std::pair<myClass, std::basic_string<char> > >; _Args = {const std::piecewise_construct_t&, std::tuple<const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&>, std::tuple<>}; _Tp = std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, std::pair<myClass, std::basic_string<char> > > >; std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<_CharT> >::allocator_type = std::allocator<std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, std::pair<myClass, std::basic_string<char> > > > >]’
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_tree.h:626:32:   required from ‘void std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::_M_construct_node(std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::_Link_type, _Args&& ...) [with _Args = {const std::piecewise_construct_t&, std::tuple<const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&>, std::tuple<>}; _Key = std::basic_string<char>; _Val = std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, std::pair<myClass, std::basic_string<char> > >; _KeyOfValue = std::_Select1st<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, std::pair<myClass, std::basic_string<char> > > >; _Compare = std::less<std::basic_string<char> >; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, std::pair<myClass, std::basic_string<char> > > >; std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::_Link_type = std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, std::pair<myClass, std::basic_string<char> > > >*]’
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_tree.h:643:21:   required from ‘std::_Rb_tree_node<_Val>* std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::_M_create_node(_Args&& ...) [with _Args = {const std::piecewise_construct_t&, std::tuple<const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&>, std::tuple<>}; _Key = std::basic_string<char>; _Val = std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, std::pair<myClass, std::basic_string<char> > >; _KeyOfValue = std::_Select1st<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, std::pair<myClass, std::basic_string<char> > > >; _Compare = std::less<std::basic_string<char> >; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, std::pair<myClass, std::basic_string<char> > > >; std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::_Link_type = std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, std::pair<myClass, std::basic_string<char> > > >*]’
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_tree.h:2398:33:   required from ‘std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::iterator std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::_M_emplace_hint_unique(std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::const_iterator, _Args&& ...) [with _Args = {const std::piecewise_construct_t&, std::tuple<const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&>, std::tuple<>}; _Key = std::basic_string<char>; _Val = std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, std::pair<myClass, std::basic_string<char> > >; _KeyOfValue = std::_Select1st<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, std::pair<myClass, std::basic_string<char> > > >; _Compare = std::less<std::basic_string<char> >; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, std::pair<myClass, std::basic_string<char> > > >; std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::iterator = std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, std::pair<myClass, std::basic_string<char> > > >; std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::const_iterator = std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, std::pair<myClass, std::basic_string<char> > > >]’
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_map.h:493:8:   required from ‘std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::mapped_type& std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::operator[](const key_type&) [with _Key = std::basic_string<char>; _Tp = std::pair<myClass, std::basic_string<char> >; _Compare = std::less<std::basic_string<char> >; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, std::pair<myClass, std::basic_string<char> > > >; std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::mapped_type = std::pair<myClass, std::basic_string<char> >; std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::key_type = std::basic_string<char>]’
<span class="error_line" onclick="ide.gotoLine('main.cpp',22)">main.cpp:22:19</span>:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/7/tuple:1652:70: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::pair >::pair()’
         second(std::forward<_Args2>(std::get<_Indexes2>(__tuple2))...)
                                                                      ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_algobase.h:64:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/ios:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/iostream:39,
                 from main.cpp:9:
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_pair.h:436:9: note: candidate: template std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(std::tuple<_Args1 ...>&, std::tuple<_Args2 ...>&, std::_Index_tuple<_Indexes1 ...>, std::_Index_tuple<_Indexes2 ...>)
         pair(tuple<_Args1...>&, tuple<_Args2...>&,
         ^~~~
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_pair.h:436:9: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/bits/unique_ptr.h:37:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/bits/locale_conv.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/locale:43,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/regex:44,
                 from h.h:11,
                 from main.cpp:10:
/usr/include/c++/7/tuple:1652:70: note:   candidate expects 4 arguments, 0 provided
         second(std::forward<_Args2>(std::get<_Indexes2>(__tuple2))...)
                                                                      ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_algobase.h:64:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/ios:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/iostream:39,
                 from main.cpp:9:
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_pair.h:375:9: note: candidate: template std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(std::piecewise_construct_t, std::tuple<_Args1 ...>, std::tuple<_Args2 ...>)
         pair(piecewise_construct_t, tuple<_Args1...>, tuple<_Args2...>);
         ^~~~
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_pair.h:375:9: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/bits/unique_ptr.h:37:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/bits/locale_conv.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/locale:43,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/regex:44,
                 from h.h:11,
                 from main.cpp:10:
/usr/include/c++/7/tuple:1652:70: note:   candidate expects 3 arguments, 0 provided
         second(std::forward<_Args2>(std::get<_Indexes2>(__tuple2))...)
                                                                      ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_algobase.h:64:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/ios:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/iostream:39,
                 from main.cpp:9:
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_pair.h:370:21: note: candidate: template::value) || (! std::is_same, _U2>::value)), myClass, std::basic_string >::_MoveConstructiblePair<_U1, _U2>() && (! std::_PCC<((! std::is_same::value) || (! std::is_same, _U2>::value)), myClass, std::basic_string >::_ImplicitlyMoveConvertiblePair<_U1, _U2>())), bool>::type  > constexpr std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(std::pair<_U1, _U2>&&)
  explicit constexpr pair(pair<_U1, _U2>&& __p)
                     ^~~~
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_pair.h:370:21: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/bits/unique_ptr.h:37:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/bits/locale_conv.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/locale:43,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/regex:44,
                 from h.h:11,
                 from main.cpp:10:
/usr/include/c++/7/tuple:1652:70: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
         second(std::forward<_Args2>(std::get<_Indexes2>(__tuple2))...)
                                                                      ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_algobase.h:64:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/ios:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/iostream:39,
                 from main.cpp:9:
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_pair.h:360:12: note: candidate: template::value) || (! std::is_same, _U2>::value)), myClass, std::basic_string >::_MoveConstructiblePair<_U1, _U2>() && std::_PCC<((! std::is_same::value) || (! std::is_same, _U2>::value)), myClass, std::basic_string >::_ImplicitlyMoveConvertiblePair<_U1, _U2>()), bool>::type  > constexpr std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(std::pair<_U1, _U2>&&)
  constexpr pair(pair<_U1, _U2>&& __p)
            ^~~~
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_pair.h:360:12: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/bits/unique_ptr.h:37:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/bits/locale_conv.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/locale:43,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/regex:44,
                 from h.h:11,
                 from main.cpp:10:
/usr/include/c++/7/tuple:1652:70: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
         second(std::forward<_Args2>(std::get<_Indexes2>(__tuple2))...)
                                                                      ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_algobase.h:64:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/ios:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/iostream:39,
                 from main.cpp:9:
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_pair.h:350:21: note: candidate: template() && (! _ImplicitlyMoveConvertiblePair<_U1, _U2>())), bool>::type  > constexpr std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(_U1&&, _U2&&)
  explicit constexpr pair(_U1&& __x, _U2&& __y)
                     ^~~~
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_pair.h:350:21: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/bits/unique_ptr.h:37:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/bits/locale_conv.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/locale:43,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/regex:44,
                 from h.h:11,
                 from main.cpp:10:
/usr/include/c++/7/tuple:1652:70: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 0 provided
         second(std::forward<_Args2>(std::get<_Indexes2>(__tuple2))...)
                                                                      ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_algobase.h:64:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/ios:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/iostream:39,
                 from main.cpp:9:
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_pair.h:341:12: note: candidate: template() && _ImplicitlyMoveConvertiblePair<_U1, _U2>()), bool>::type  > constexpr std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(_U1&&, _U2&&)
  constexpr pair(_U1&& __x, _U2&& __y)
            ^~~~
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_pair.h:341:12: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/bits/unique_ptr.h:37:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/bits/locale_conv.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/locale:43,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/regex:44,
                 from h.h:11,
                 from main.cpp:10:
/usr/include/c++/7/tuple:1652:70: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 0 provided
         second(std::forward<_Args2>(std::get<_Indexes2>(__tuple2))...)
                                                                      ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_algobase.h:64:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/ios:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/iostream:39,
                 from main.cpp:9:
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_pair.h:332:17: note: candidate: template(), bool>::type  > std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(const _T1&, _U2&&)
        explicit pair(const _T1& __x, _U2&& __y)
                 ^~~~
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_pair.h:332:17: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/bits/unique_ptr.h:37:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/bits/locale_conv.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/locale:43,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/regex:44,
                 from h.h:11,
                 from main.cpp:10:
/usr/include/c++/7/tuple:1652:70: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 0 provided
         second(std::forward<_Args2>(std::get<_Indexes2>(__tuple2))...)
                                                                      ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_algobase.h:64:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/ios:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/iostream:39,
                 from main.cpp:9:
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_pair.h:325:18: note: candidate: template(), bool>::type  > constexpr std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(const _T1&, _U2&&)
        constexpr pair(const _T1& __x, _U2&& __y)
                  ^~~~
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_pair.h:325:18: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/bits/unique_ptr.h:37:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/bits/locale_conv.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/locale:43,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/regex:44,
                 from h.h:11,
                 from main.cpp:10:
/usr/include/c++/7/tuple:1652:70: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 0 provided
         second(std::forward<_Args2>(std::get<_Indexes2>(__tuple2))...)
                                                                      ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_algobase.h:64:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/ios:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/iostream:39,
                 from main.cpp:9:
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_pair.h:318:27: note: candidate: template, std::allocator > >(), bool>::type  > constexpr std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(_U1&&, const _T2&)
        explicit constexpr pair(_U1&& __x, const _T2& __y)
                           ^~~~
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_pair.h:318:27: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/bits/unique_ptr.h:37:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/bits/locale_conv.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/locale:43,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/regex:44,
                 from h.h:11,
                 from main.cpp:10:
```

The error is much longer than this

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Does changing `MyClass m()` to `MyClass m{}` or `MyClass m = MyClass()` help you?

Comment: `MyClass` Vs `Myclass` perhaps?

Comment: Sounds like vexing parse, please enable your compiler warnings

Comment: I'll add the compilation error I get to the question, it is pretty long.

Comment: btw comments cannot be trusted, but `class MyClass {};` is a perfectly working class. If you do leave out stuff you just  need to make sure that your minimal example still reproduces the error / problem

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I avoid most vexing parse with direct value initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51707710/how-can-i-avoid-most-vexing-parse-with-direct-value-initialization)

Comment: This does not seem like my issue here, because my class instance seems to work fine as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is caused by the lack of default constructor for `myClass`.

`map::operator[]` must be able to default construct the maps value type (because it returns a reference to an entry in the map and so must be able to add values to the map if they are not already present).

The error is actually pretty clear, once you learn to read the error message

> no matching function for call to ‘std::pair<>::pair()

The compiler hasn't been able to synthesize a default constructor for the pair, because of the lack of a default constructor for `myClass`.

Comment: I just added a constructor to the code above to show how my class works, does that still seem wrong?

Comment: @NikitParakh The problem is that it isn't a default constructor. Add this `class myClass { ... public: myClass() {} ... };`.

Comment: Thank you, that worked, I had been scratching by head for so long