# Why are parens needed for the first argument to std::string in this code?

Tags: c++, string, std

I'm trying to load text from a file into a `const char*` instance. I came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18398230/3280538) and adapted it as:

```
std::ifstream vertex_shader_stream("shaders/demo1_vert.glsl");
std::string vertex_shader_string(
  (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(vertex_shader_stream)),
  std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
const char *vertex_shader_bytes = vertex_shader_string.c_str();
```

What I'm having trouble understanding is why the first argument to `std::string` is wrapped in parens `()` as `(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(vertex_shader_stream))`. I thought this might have been some redundant typing, but it appears to fail without them when calling `c_str`

```
error: request for member ‘c_str’ in ‘vertex_shader_string’, which is of non-class type ‘std::string(std::istreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> >, std::istreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> > (*)())’ {aka ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>(std::istreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> >, std::istreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> > (*)())’}
[build]    61 |   const char *vertex_shader_text = vertex_shader_string.c_str();
[build]       |                                                         ^~~~~
```

I'm not groking the error here, can someone explain this to me in detail what's going on? I'm sure this is probably a duplicate, so feel free to close vote if that's the case, I just don't know the right terms to search for!

Thanks!

Comment: [Most vexing parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14077608/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-most-vexing-parse) ?

Comment: See dupe [How can I avoid most vexing parse with direct value initialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51707710/how-can-i-avoid-most-vexing-parse-with-direct-value-initialization)

Comment: @Jason Thanks so much. I don't think I would have found that on my own quickly. These cpp concepts have such out to lunch names sometimes.

Comment: @Jason So if I'm reading this correctly, the compiler thought I was making a function called `vertex_shader_string` where the first argument is a `std::istreambuf_iterator<char>` ?

Comment: Yes, exactly. See the warning [here](https://godbolt.org/z/sno3donWa). This is why it is recommended to [always enable all warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57842756/why-should-i-always-enable-compiler-warnings).

Comment: @Jason Yep, would have thought warnings would be the default. Getting all my ducks in a row for starting cpp dev is going to be an interesting ride. Thanks again!